# Winwheel callbackFinished doesn't work in Symfony Webpack Encore

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm using Winwheel.js library to create a spinning wheel for my Symfony project with Webpack Encore. I'm trying to trigger an alert after the spinning animation finishes using the callbackFinished option. However, the callback doesn't seem to be working.

I'm using :

```
   "gsap": "2.1.3",
    "winwheel": "^1.0.1"
```

Here's my code:

```
import Winwheel from 'Winwheel'
import TweenMax from 'gsap'

const theWheel = new Winwheel({
    'canvasId': 'myCanvas',
    'numSegments'  : 8,     // Specify number of segments.
    'outerRadius'  : 170,   // Set outer radius so wheel fits inside the background.
    'textFontSize' : 28,    // Set font size as desired.
    'responsive'   : true,
    'textMargin'     : 15,
    'textOrientation' : 'horizontal',    // Set orientation. horizontal, vertical, curved.
    'textDirection' : 'reversed',
    'textFontFamily'  : 'Courier',     // Monospace font best for vertical and curved.
    'textAlignment'  : 'outer',         // Set alignment: inner, outer, center.
    'segments'     :        // Define segments including colour and text.
        [
            {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 1'},
            {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 2'},
            {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 3'},
            {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 4'},
            {'fillStyle' : '#eae56f', 'text' : 'Prize 5'},
            {'fillStyle' : '#89f26e', 'text' : 'Prize 6'},
            {'fillStyle' : '#7de6ef', 'text' : 'Prize 7'},
            {'fillStyle' : '#e7706f', 'text' : 'Prize 8'}
        ],
    'pins' : false,
    'animation' :           // Specify the animation to use.
        {
            'type'     : 'spinToStop',
            'duration' : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
            'spins'    : 8,     // Number of complete spins.
            'easing'       : 'Power4.easeOut',
            'stopAngle'    : null,
            'direction'    : 'clockwise',
            'repeat'       : 0,
            'yoyo'         : false,
            'callbackFinished' : alertPrize
        }
});

function alertPrize(indicatedSegment)
{
    // Do basic alert of the segment text. You would probably want to do something more interesting with this information.
    alert("You have won " + indicatedSegment.text);
}

const tourner_la_roue = document.getElementById('tourner_la_roue');

tourner_la_roue.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    theWheel.startAnimation();
})
```

Here's the webpack loader config :

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        autoprefixer: {}
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Here's my twig :

```
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="450">  </canvas>
   ...
   {% block javascripts %}
     {{ encore_entry_script_tags('winwheel') }}
   {% endblock %}
```